# Xcode now displays Marks as red flags - any way to revert it back to the simple line it used to be?

Tags: xcode, comments

Just updated to XCode 15 and see that my MARK comments now display in the navigator as Red Flags, where they used to be nice clean simple header lines.  Is there any way to get it back to the way it used to be?  (I'm not a fan of the red flag)

[image]